# Having problems joining a database to an Availability Group on the secondary replica

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Trying to join a database to an AG on the secondary replica, I'm getting the error:

> The remote copy of database "ABC" has not been rolled forward to a
> point in time that is encompassed in the local copy of the database
> log. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:1412)

I have looked up this error and followed the "fix" to restore both full and t-log backups in no recovery mode on the secondary replica, but still getting the error.

It is a SQL 2019 installation with SQL services running with the same group managed service account on both replicas. I am however attempting to add the test database to the AG logged in as my Windows account which has sysadmin privs. Could this be the cause of the problem? Do I need to login to SQL as the gmsa to be able to add databases to the AG? But authentication is not mixed mode, it is Windows.

I will appreciate some guidance on this please.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're taking log backups, you'll have to stop them while you're setting up a new secondary, otherwise the log will truncate on the primary, causing this error.

So, disable log backups, add the database to the Availability Group on the primary, and either wait for automatic seeding to complete its tasks, or manually restore (with norecovery) a copy of the database on the secondary, then join it to the AG.  Once the secondary copies of the database are successfully synchronized with the primary, resume the transaction log backups.